# Create OpenSSL certificates signed by myself

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm using boost ssl for server and client, and I have a model for server/client program in my mind, and I'm not sure it's gonna work.

**The model I have in my mind is to be the only authority for certificates of my program. My main question is: How can I do that?**

In my server program, I define keys as follows:

```
    context_.use_certificate_chain_file("../sslkeys/server.crt");
    context_.use_private_key_file("../sslkeys/server.key", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
    context_.use_tmp_dh_file("../sslkeys/dh512.pem");
```

I create/sign those keys/certificates using:

```
$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
$ cp server.key server.key.secure
$ openssl rsa -in server.key.secure -out server.key
$ openssl dhparam -out dh512.pem 512
```

For my client program, I would like to create a certificate and sign it by my "server.key", because I think (and I could be wrong, please correct me if I'm) that's the way to do it. The client program requires a key using the command:

```
ctx.load_verify_file("../sslkeys/client.csr");
```

So I created a key, which I signed using the server key, with the following commands:

```
$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out client.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in client.csr -signkey ../sslkeys/server.key -out client.crt
```

Now when I run my client and try to connect the server, I get the error: `Handshake failed: certificate verify failed`

What is wrong in what I'm doing? And how can I achieve the model I mentioned?

If you require any additional information, please ask.

Thanks for any efforts.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signing certificate has no rights to sign, because it has not the CA flag set. Signing will still work, but verification will fail. Since there are already lots of guides on the internet which will show in detail how to do it right so you might just look [here](http://www.area536.com/projects/be-your-own-certificate-authority-with-openssl/) or [here](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/) for more details.

Also, using only a 512 bit Diffie-Hellman reduces the security of the key exchange to 512 bit, which is exploitable today (see also Logjam attack). The 2048 RSA key does not help here. And using 512 bit might not even work if you use the latest version of OpenSSL which just increased the minimal size to 768 bits for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this, and give you a check if this works. May I ask, though,  if I increase the dh key to 2048, will that solve the problem? Or are there other considerations to take into account?

Comment: Increasing the DH key to 2048 is fine, as long a the client supports it.  With Java you would need at least JDK8 and there might be issues with Internet Explorer. See also http://blog.ivanristic.com/2013/08/increasing-dhe-strength-on-apache.html.

Comment: I have now CA keys (ca.key and ca.crt), and server/client keys that are signed by my CA. But what is then my Certificate Chain File in this case that I have to provide to my server program? None of the links explain that concept. I tried the possible combinations of my keys and they don't work. Could you please tell me what my certificate chain should be? Thanks.

Comment: If you have only the root-CA which then signed the leaf certificate directly, then the only certificate you should send is the leaf certificate. Of course the root-CA must be trusted by the client already.

Comment: I'm sorry this is not a clear answer to my last question. My program requests a chain file + a key. The key is signed directly by my ca key. Now what about the chain file? In the list of files I provided, how do I produce a chain certificate file? Thank you.

Comment: The chain consists of the leaf certificate and intermediate certificates. Since you have no intermediates it is just the lead certificate.

Comment: When I use the lead certificate, it says "Exception: use_private_key_file: key values mismatch"... how could this happen? I recreated the keys twice and I keep getting this! Please help!

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are really doing. The question for sure does not reflect what you are actually doing now. I suspect that you mixed the key files for leaf certificate and CA certificate.

Comment: Can we please talk on chat a little bit to clarify this? I'm quite sure I'm not mixing anything. I'm lost whether this is a bug or a mistake from my side.

Comment: Sorry, but not in the next days. But I recommend that you document each step you are doing so that others can see what goes wrong.

Comment: I'm writing a new question with this problem... I was hoping you could help me quicker.